# Color a vtk Unstructured Grid , face by face

Tags: c++, visualization, vtk

I want to add colors according to the given scalars of faces to a vtk unstructured grid.
How do I extract the faces of unstructured grid to assign scalars?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK. So this is how I did it. vtk unstructured grid does not support face data. Therefore you have to create each face as a cell and add color scalars as cell data. vtkUnstructuredGridGeometryFilter gives the faces of the outer surface only.

Thanks.